# Fourier transform of $\,e^{-ax}\!\operatorname{erfc}(x)$

Tags: fourier-transform, error-function

Can someone help with calculating the Fourier transform of $e^{-ax}\!\operatorname{erfc}(x)$, where $a < 0$. There are some posts talking about how to calculate the Fourier transform of $\operatorname{erfc}(x)$, which is derived from distribution theory. The problem I am asking will not a distribution. I'm not sure how to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: Hint.  
$$
\int \!{{\rm e}^{-ax}}{\rm erfc} \left( x \right) \,{\rm d}x=-{\frac {
{{\rm e}^{-ax}}}{a}}+{\frac {{\rm erf} \left(x\right){{\rm e}^{-ax}}}{
a}}-{\frac {1}{a}{{\rm e}^{{{{a}^{2}}/{4}}}}{\rm erf} \left(x+{
\frac {a}{2}}\right)}
$$
and Laplace transform of a function is related to the Laplace transform of its integral.

Comment: You meant Fourier transform? Also your integration does not seem to be right.

Comment: Isn't something wrong here? Isn't $\operatorname{erfc}(x) \approx 2$ on the negative side where $e^{-ax}$ is big?

Comment: Yes it should be a < 0, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Fourier transform of

$$f(x)=e^{-a x}\, \text{erfc}(x)\tag{1}$$

only converges for $\Re(a)<0$:

$$F(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\, e^{i x \omega}\,dx=-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\ e^{\frac{1}{4} (a-i \omega)^2}}{a-i \omega}\text{ if }\Re(a)<0\tag{2}$$

The result illustrated in formula (2) above was given by Mathematica.

Comment: Yes you are right, should be $a < 0$. I was copying pasting a simplified version of my equation and got the sign wrong. Would you mind sharing the line of Mathematica code here?

Comment: @user123 I evaluated it two different ways: 1) 1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Integrate[Exp[-a x] Erfc[x] Exp[I x w]], {x,-Infinity,Infinity},GenerateConditions->True], and 2) FourierTransform[Exp[-a x] Erfc[x],x,w,GenerateConditions->True].

Comment: Also what about $e^{-ax}\text{i}^1\operatorname{erfc}(x)$? Does Mathematica have $\text{i}^1\operatorname{erfc}(x)$ or do I have to use the iterative relation to write $\text{i}^1\operatorname{erfc}(x)$ in terms of $\text{i}^0\operatorname{erfc}(x)$ and $\text{i}^{-1}\operatorname{erfc}(x)$?

Comment: @user123 I'm not sure what you mean since $i^1$ is a constant which can be moved outside of the Fourier transform integral.

Comment: Oh it is not a constant. It is called the Repeated Integrals of the Complementary Error
Function. They satisfy the relation $2 n \cdot \operatorname{i}^n\!\operatorname{erfc} z = \operatorname{i}^{n-2}\!\operatorname{erfc} z -2 z \cdot \operatorname{i}^{n-1}\!\operatorname{erfc} z$

Comment: @user123 If you mean $f(x)=\int\text{erfc}(x)\,dx=x\ \text{erfc}(x)-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$, then Mathematica indicates the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ is $-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} e^{\frac{1}{4} (a-i \omega )^2}}{(a-i \omega )^2}\text{ if }\Re(a)<0$.

Comment: I will wait for a bit to see if someone can post a theoretical proof of the results. If not, I will just accept your answer. Thanks a lot!